# Upgrade from ServiceStack V3 to V4 causes issues with clients still using V3 (/syncreply/ vs /reply/)

Tags: c#, servicestack

We recently upgraded SS from V3 to V4 and have found that our C# clients are now failing because  breaking changes were introduced when the PredefinedRoutes were renamed from /syncreply/ to /sync/.

My question is... how can we keep those older clients in the wild still working while we update them from the top (server) down? (Updating all our clients and partners at the same time is not an option.)

Is there a way to add a custom httphandler or maybe a Host setting i am missing?

PS: The only route that is using the /syncreply/ lookup is Authenticate.

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 0):

You can change the existing **v3 Service Clients** to use the new pre-defined Routes by setting the `UseNewPredefinedRoutes` property, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    UseNewPredefinedRoutes = true
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer... but I'm afraid that modifying the client is not an option as we dont control the upgrade cycles of clients. 

What I ended up doing was disabling Predefined Routes feature, and building our own Authentication DTOs, then adding the route "/json/syncreply/auth" to the new auth DTO (which will re direct any service lookups). Its not ideal and is a touch hacky, but it works as long as the only DTO the .NET client uses without a route was the default SS "Auth" DTO. 

We will eventually deprecate "/json/syncreply/auth" - but for now it works fine.